# How to create a sticky header which dynamically changes between mobile and desktop (No hamburger)

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, navigation

I'd like to have a sticky header navigation menu that contains Text and an icon on a desktop browser, but only icons on a mobile device (as illustrated in my sketch at the bottom of this post - ignore colors used.) I've started writing the code here: https://codepen.io/jord8on/pen/pxgjZq

[This article](https://medium.com/@kollinz/hamburger-menu-alternatives-for-mobile-navigation-a3a3beb555b8) gives another exmaple of what I'd love to have. (specifically the 3rd of the "Tabbed Navigation" samples)

Here's what I need some help with:

1. When a browser width shrinks below 600px I'd like the labels/text next to the icons to disappear and only show the icons.
2. I want the .navbar to be sticky and remain atop the screen on desktop **and** mobile, when a users scrolls down.
3. I'd like to have the "active" menu item highlighted, depending on where a person is, in the site.

   1. Home, Courses, Resources, and Events are all going to be different areas within a Wordpress site.
   2. The Community tab will link to a subdomain which is running a Discourse community

Any help would be so much appreciated!

[image]

Current CSS/HTML:

```css
/* Style the navigation bar */
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #B7234C;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Navbar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 20%;
}

/* Navbar links on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #961d3f;
}

/* Current/active navbar link */
.active {
  background-color: #d6295a;
}

/* Add responsiveness - will automatically display the navbar vertically instead of horizontally on screens less than 500 pixels */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Load font awesome icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Load font awesome icon library -->

<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments"></i> Community</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Courses</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i> Resources</a>
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i> Events</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try wrapping your link text in a span, then give all of those spans a class that is only visible on desktop. Or, use the opposite logic and make in not visible on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put a span between your texts in your anchor tags and target it on the media query with a display none
2. Put a position fixed on  your navbar you might need to reset the margins on the body. I added 4000px on height to reflect the sticky scroll.
3. Depending on the page change the class on the body tag and edit in the CSS when needed this example is targeting the events icon.
   [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmEEoJ)
   Hope this helps.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 4000px;
}
/* Style the navigation bar */
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #B7234C;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Navbar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 20%;
}

/* Navbar links on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #961d3f;
}

/* Current/active navbar link */
/* In your html you change the body class and target it in here */
/* This example uses the events icon which is a child 5 in the navigation */
.events .navbar a:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #d6295a;
}

/* Add responsiveness - will automatically display the navbar vertically instead of horizontally on screens less than 500 pixels */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  
  .navbar{
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar span{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Change the class name depending on the page that you're in then modify the css -->
<body class="events">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Load font awesome icon library -->

<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i><span> Home</span></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments"></i> <span>Community</span></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i><span> Courses</span></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i> <span>Resources</span></a>
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i><span> Events</span></a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. What would be the cleanest way to add a 1px divider line between each of the buttons and still have them spaced evenly and centered? I was trying, but you can see I've butchered it: https://codepen.io/jord8on/pen/GYopYM

Comment: That was a clever use of CSS. Nice

Answer (score 1):

I commented above, but here's an example:

@jord8on I added another attribute to the navbar in the code above. Keep in mind that you may need to add a top margin to any subsequent elements at an equal height to the navbar. Position fixed takes that element out of the flow of the DOM. <del>As for the third part, is each page in a separate html file? Or how are you making the navbar globally available?</del> You'll need to write some PHP to echo the "active" class into your links with Wordpress.

This got a bit lengthy for commenting, so here's the easier to read option. Sorry about that.

```
   /* Style the navigation bar */
   .navbar {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #B7234C;
      overflow: auto;
      //Add this to the navbar element
      position: fixed;
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .navbar a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
      }
      .mob-off {
          display: none;
      }
    }

    <div class="navbar">
      <a class="active" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="mob-off">Home</span>
      </a> 
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments"></i> <span class="mob-off">Community</span>
      </a> 
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit">
        </i> <span class="mob-off">Courses</span>
      </a> 
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i> <span class="mob-off">Resources</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i> <span class="mob-off">Events</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Brilliant @DonCarlosII ! That takes care of my main question. Any chance you could offer another answer or edit this ⬆︎ answer to include a response to my other questions... 

2. I want the .navbar to be sticky and remain atop the screen on desktop and mobile, when a users scrolls down.

3. I'd like to have the "active" menu item highlighted, depending on where a person is, in one of my two sites (over which this is acting as a global header).

Comment: in a former comment you asked how I was planning to identify the page the users is on (to determine which tab is "Active"). I was thinking it might be best to identify where a user is, based on some javascript that looks at the url to identify based on the main site directory or a subdirectory where the user is, at any given time. Maybe there's a better practice for this though. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You could definitely do that with javascript, but if you're in the world of WordPress anyway, it wouldn't be that hard to figure out how to make a dynamic menu. That would likely be a topic for another question lol. I don't want to over complicate this one.